# Adjacently Dependent AJAX (improved)

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, api, google-chrome

This question was posted a couple of days ago, but since I'm a nub it was filled with spaghetti code and that sort of thing (please pardon the form handling as well) That aside, I've added some notes and given some context, but the problem still lies in the second AJAX call.

This is the error that Chrome is throwing "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

I have hidden the URL because it contains an API key that I would rather not share.

*Any and all criticisms are warmly welcomed*

```js
/*
This module will take a user's name, return an ID
then search more stats in the api with the ID.
*/


var search = document.getElementById('search');
search.addEventListener('click', function(){


 var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
 var player_name = document.getElementById('player_name').value;
 var player_id;

 // Interpolated API URLs
 var name_url = 'URL.pre'+player_name+'URL.end';
 var stats_url; //nested in the second ajax call to pass updated player_id


 // Get player ID
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var id_return_text;
 xhr.onload = function(){
  if(xhr.status === 200) {
   id_return_text = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
   player_id = id_return_text[player_name].id;
   demo.innerHTML = id_return_text[player_name].name +', your player ID is: '+player_id;
  }
 };
 xhr.open('GET', name_url, true);
 xhr.send();
 

 // Search stats with ID
 var xhr_2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var stats_return_text;
 xhr.done = function(){
  stats_url = "URL.pre"+player_id+"URL.end";
  if(xhr_2.status == 200) {
   stats_return_text = JSON.parse(xhr_2.responseText);
   demo.innerHTML += stats_return_text['playerStatsSummaries'].playerStatType;
  }
 };
 xhr_2.open("GET",stats_url, true);
 xhr_2.send();


});
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <img id="duck" src="duck.png" alt="duck">
 <div class="form_wrapper">
  <h1 id="app_header">*QUACK* What's Your player ID?</h1>
  <form>
   <input
    type="text"
    id="player_name" 
    placeholder="Summoner Name">
   <input type="button" id="search" value="Search">
  </form>
 </div>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: The error should be quite clear, `https:URL.pre` is not a valid URL, something like `https://URL.pre` would be though, so it's probably just a typo.

Comment: I'll fix that. It's actually a typo in my question. I didn't post a real url.

Comment: The error still claims that the URL you're using doesn't have a valid protocol *(for cross-origin calls)*, so something is wrong with that URL, and it's going to be hard to help you without knowing the *real* URL ?

Comment: The URL will eventually be hidden on the server and contains an API key that I am responsible for, so I can't give it out freely, and you won't be able to run the code. I've just now run a series of tests with my URL and a set of player IDs, so under those circumstances, I don't believe there is anything wrong with the URL.

Comment: You might consider posting a fake URL which follows the correct URL protocols. While we don't need the actual API key, we do need to see how all of the state of the app might be getting pushed together (especially important due to all of the asynchronicity in JS). It's not a question of whether the URL is correct or incorrect, when directly hit by the browser, but your string concatenation, or state management, or whathaveyou, likely does have a direct impact on this.

Comment: I don't think there's any mistaking that error message, it's basically telling you that the URL used does not have a `http://` or `https://` protocol *(and a few other valid options)* , so open the console and inspect the requests, then you'll see what the actual URL's are, and what fails etc.

Comment: @Norgard, I've updated the URLs and only removed the key itself.

Comment: @JoshuaT You are hosting this on a Localhost webserver, and not just opening the "index.html" file from Chrome, right?  What is the URL in your browser's bar? Again, you don't have to post sensitive information, but the scheme and a reasonable URI for that scheme. This error also throws if you are browsing the site in a different scheme than what's supported, so it's not only the protocol of what you're asking for, but where the browser thinks you *are* as well.

Comment: I ran this on a localhost server and it threw this error instead "http://localhost/api%20testing/undefined 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) @ script.js:47"

Comment: @JoshuaT Cool! That's closer to what I expected. Your chrome issue is because you're running it as a `file://`. Chrome doesn't allow `file://`s to make requests for content from the internet (or other `file://`s for that matter). The rest of it is async madness, and what looks like a typo (not sure if it's the code, or the example, though (`xhr.done` looks like it should be `xhr2.done`). I'll have an answer to take care of your real problem, though.

Comment: Great thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your primary error was that if you need to make CORS requests (or any AJAX requests, really), you need to run the code from a server (even localhost).

Google (and most browsers) will freak out at you if your page's protocol is "file:///" and you're trying to load things from the internet (or vice versa).  And "file:///" cannot make requests for other files, either.

Future reference: you also can't make "http" requests from an "https" page.

That out of the way, the second issue (the one that was being hidden by CORS security), is that your AJAX requests are being run in parallel right now.

In order to make this work the way you think it should (*after the first one returns, run the second one*), you would need to:

1. move all of the code at the bottom, relating to `xhr_2` inside of the `xhr.onload`
2. move all of the code inside of `xhr.done` at the bottom inside of the `xhr.onload` and replace all of the duplicate information (and use the references to the returned results directly)

This results in something like:

```
var search = document.getElementById('search');
search.addEventListener('click', function(){


  var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
  var player_name = document.getElementById('player_name').value;
  var player_id;

  // Interpolated API URLs
  var name_url = 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/'+player_name+'?api_key=<THIS IS THE API KEY>';
  var stats_url; //nested in the second ajax call to pass updated player_id


  // Get player ID
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var id_return_text;
  xhr.onload = function(){
    if(xhr.status === 200) {
      id_return_text = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      player_id = id_return_text[player_name].id;
      demo.innerHTML = id_return_text[player_name].name +', your player ID is: '+player_id;

      // Dropped the XHR_2 stuff here
      var xhr_2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var stats_return_text;
      stats_url = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/"+player_id+"/summary?season=SEASON2016&api_key=<THIS IS THE API KEY>";

      // CHANGED THIS TO BE XHR_2.onload -- IN HERE I KNOW XHR_1 IS ALREADY FINISHED
      xhr_2.onload = function(){
        if(xhr_2.status == 200) {
          stats_return_text = JSON.parse(xhr_2.responseText);
          demo.innerHTML += stats_return_text['playerStatsSummaries'].playerStatType;
        }
      };

      xhr_2.open("GET",stats_url, true);
      xhr_2.send();
    }
  };
  xhr.open('GET', name_url, true);
  xhr.send();

});
```

That should solve practically all of your woes.

The point of this is that `onload` is a callback which gets fired long after the program has been run, but `xhr_2` was firing immediately after you requested data for `xhr_1` (not after it was returning the data).

As such, `player_id` was undefined.

We want to wait until after we know we have `player_id`, and we know we have it (or some error) when we're inside the callback to `xhr_1.onload`.

This gets terribly confusing and very nested, and while I think that Promises and Async Functions / Generators are brilliant solutions for managing that complexity, that's way beyond the scope of this; so instead, I'd suggest looking at some functional composition, to simplify all of this:

```
function noop () { } // do nothing

function getJSON (url, onload, onerror) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  onload = onload || noop; // what I've been given or nothing
  onerror = onerror || noop; // " "

  xhr.onload = function () {
    var data;
    var error;
    try {
      // it's possible for parse to throw on malformed JSON
      data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    } catch (e) {
      error = e;
    }

    return error ? onerror(error) : onload(data); // fire one or the other (don't fall into the handler, if onload throws)
  };
  xhr.onerror = onerror;

  xhr.open("GET", url);
  xhr.send();
}


// localize URL construction
function buildPlayerIdUrl (name) { return "https://______" + name + "_____"; } 
function buildPlayerStatsUrl (id) { return "https://______" + id + "_____"; }


// gets player by name and runs a function after the player has been loaded
function getPlayer (player_name, done, error) {
  var id_url = buildPlayerIdUrl(player_name);

  function buildPlayer (response) {
    var player = response[player_name];
    return player;
  }

  function onload (response) {
    done(buildPlayer(response));
  }

  // Load the JSON, build the player, pass the player to done()
  getJSON(url, onload, error);
}


// get stats by player id and runs a function after the stats have been loaded
function getPlayerStats (player_id, done, error) {
  var stats_url = buildPlayerStatsUrl(player_id);

  function buildStats (response) {
    var summary = response.playerStatsSummaries;
    return summary;
  }
  function onload (response) {
    done(buildStats(response));
  }

  // Load the JSON, build the stats, pass the stats to done()
  getJSON(stats_url, onload, error);
}


// perform a search by player name
// note: All changes in step-number (1, 2, 3) are asynchronous,
// and thus, must be nested in callbacks of some sort
function search (player_name) {
  // Step 1: load the player
  getPlayer(playerName, function (player) {
    // Step 2a: update the DOM with the player name/id
    updatePlayerDom(player);
    // Step 2b: load the player stats
    getPlayerStats(player.id, function (stats) {
      // Step 3: update the DOM with the stats
      updateStatsDom(stats);
    });
  });
}

// player DOM update; keeping it nice and simple
function updatePlayerDom (player) {
  document.querySelector(".Player-id").textContent = player.id;
  document.querySelector(".Player-name").textContent = player.name;
}

// stats DOM update; same as above
function updateStatsDom (stats) {
  document.querySelector(".Player-stats").textContent = stats.playerStatType;
}

// bootstrap yourself to your UI
some_button.onclick = function () {
  var player_name = some_input.value;
  search(player_name); // kick the whole thing off
};
```

It's definitely more code, but it's also simpler to make edits to each individual piece, without stepping on the toes of other pieces.

It's (hopefully) also easier to see the *_eventual timeline_* of all of the pieces, and how they flow, inside of the `search( )` itself.

Comment: What an amazing answer! Thank you so very much. I will learn a lot from this. I wish I could +10! I am still new to this platform, so I can't actually give any more than a check mark :(

Comment: I may have nearly wrapped my head around your concept. It was probably nothing to you, but for me it was absolutely brilliant, and an excellent view into some nub friendly functional programming. Cheers good sir.

Comment: No worries. And yeah, with a little practice, it becomes easier to write clean little bits and pieces like that. Surprisingly, it’s still rare to find people who write production code in similarly neat ways -- not to say that what I’ve written here is immaculate; it’s not. Just oddly rare, given how flexible JS is. When you’re ready to go down the rabbit hole, you should check out map/reduce, Promises, ES6 arrow functions...  ...they might blow your mind, and make most of the nesting go away